# Is the turtle module in python just a learning tool

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm a beginner/intermediate programmer and i've recently been introduced to the turtle module as part of my curriculum in learning to be a programmer. I've been making some pretty cool stuff with it, but i was just wondering how far can i really go with using the turtle module? Is it something  professional developers use to build apps/software for clients, or is it just a learning tool for new programmers to help facilitate their learning and understanding of GUI before moving on to the more powerful frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve personally never heard of anyone using turtle in the professional world but I looked at [turtle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#introduction) and found this:

> ***Turtle graphics is a popular way for introducing programming to kids.*** *It was part of the original Logo programming language developed by Wally Feurzeig, Seymour Papert and Cynthia Solomon in 1967.*

Comment: Turtle is fine for all ages just as much as Scratch is for all ages. This seems mostly from a historical time back when things were "for kids" and "for adults" in programming, which is a narrow perspective. I used Python turtle in an AI class in graduate school and Harvard CS50 uses Scratch (generally considered even more "kid-oriented" than Py turtle). It's generally true that serious production apps aren't using Turtle, though.